# PHP array search ignore possible first match

Tags: php, explode

the link is: http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1840309/?ref_=hm_cht_t1
i am using

`$sprangd = explode('/',$imdb_url);
echo $sprangd[4];
$imdb = array_search('tt', $sprangd);`

right now. but it will return http:
if it ever finds http: OR https: it needs to go on searching. im looking for this part of the string: tt1840309
how would i do it? im doing it this way because the link might be www.imdb.com/title/tt1840309/?ref_=hm_cht_t1 sometimes and sometimes only tt1840309 which is why i cant echo the array out by set numbers. since it will be dynamic.

Comment: have you tried http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php might be better

Comment: Knowing always there is HTTP in the first element of the array just do unset($sprangd[0]); before search

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use regular expression. This way you don't care is url starting with www, http or https.

When url is only the title id without other part of the url, the regex will return empty array:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1840309/?ref_=hm_cht_t1';
preg_match("/title\/(?P<titleId>[\w\d]+)\//", $url, $match);
echo isset($match['titleId']) ? $match['titleId'] : $url;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a combination of [`parse_url()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) and [`preg_match()`](https://www.php.net/preg_match):

```
$parsed_url = parse_url('http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1840309/?ref_=hm_cht_t1');
preg_match('/\/title\/(?P<title>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\/[.]*/', $parsed_url['path'], $matches);
var_dump($matches['title']);
```

Will return: `tt1840309`